# How to get the first and last day of every month using sql(without procedures) for n months

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

Need to get the dates for past months for n months
n=no of months(5)

Expected o/p if running on 6th june:

```
01-01-2021 31-01-2021
01-02-2021 28-02-2021
01-03-2021 31-03-2021
01-04-2021 30-04-2021
01-05-2021 31-05-2021
```

I dont want to use any packages from python as they are not installed in my server and cant be imported

Comment: If any answer helped you to resolve the issue, take a moment to accept/upvote the answer to close the thread as resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Try this spark-sql

```
spark.sql("""
with t1( select sequence(1, 5, 1) seq, date'2021-06-06' dt  ),
     t2( select explode(seq) a, dt from t1 ),
     t3( select add_months(dt,-a) d1 ,day(dt) dy from t2 )
     select date_format(d1,'yyyy-MM-01') d2, last_day(date_format(d1,'yyyy-MM-01')) d3 from t3 order by d2
""").show(false)
```

Another solution:

You can use the spark in-built range(n) table.

```
spark.sql("""
with t1( select id+1 id, date'2021-06-06' dt from range(5) ),
     t2( select add_months(dt,-id) d1 , day(dt) dy from t1 )
     select date_format(d1,'yyyy-MM-01') d2, last_day(date_format(d1,'yyyy-MM-01')) d3 from t2 order by d2
""").show(false)

+----------+----------+
|d2        |d3        |
+----------+----------+
|2021-01-01|2021-01-31|
|2021-02-01|2021-02-28|
|2021-03-01|2021-03-31|
|2021-04-01|2021-04-30|
|2021-05-01|2021-05-31|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`concat`** function with **`transform`** higher order functions.

**`Example:`**

```
n=6

spark.sql(f"select explode(transform(sequence(1,{n}), n -> (to_date(concat_ws('-','2018',n,'01')) as d2,last_day(to_date(concat_ws('-','2018',n,'01')))as d3)))").\
select("col.*").\
show(10,False)
#+----------+----------+
#|d2        |d3        |
#+----------+----------+
#|2018-01-01|2018-01-31|
#|2018-02-01|2018-02-28|
#|2018-03-01|2018-03-31|
#|2018-04-01|2018-04-30|
#|2018-05-01|2018-05-31|
#+----------+----------+
```